# Clear part of the data from a two-dimension integer array

Tags: vb.net, multidimensional-array

If my array is A(i,j) can I use Array.Clear to zero all of the elements for i=2, for example.  It does not work as I expected.

Comment: That depends on the implementation of the `Clear` method. And that implementation is probably strongly related to the programming language that you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this example.  If I want to initialize all the elements for the second row (index = 1) I specify the starting position in the array ordered by row ascending, column ascending and the number of records to clear as the number of columns in your array.

```
Dim arr(,) As Integer = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}
        Array.Clear(arr, 1 * 3, 3)
```

Clearing the entire array would be

```
Array.Clear(arr,0,6)
```

Comment: Well, John, this sure works - I don't see what I was doing wrong, but thanks very much for the quick reply.