# Clearing a 2D array?

Tags: vb.net, multidimensional-array

Ive been trying to reset a 2D array with array.clear, to no avail. I looked at several forums suggesting I use the code below, but it throws an indexOutOfRange exception.

```
Array.Clear(scoreArray, 0, scoreArray.Length)

for reference this is the array declaration
Dim scoreArray(3, 4) As Integer
```

Comment: I don't get the exception when I run that code.

Comment: fixed it, it was caused by one of the counters I am using with the array.

Comment: See:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888312/clear-part-of-the-data-from-a-two-dimension-integer-array

Answer (score -1, accepted):

error is caused by one of the counters not being reset along with the array, too lazy to figure out which so I just reset them all

```
playerCount = 4
    textCount = 0
    labelCount = 0
```

Comment: None of those variables are used in the statement you say gets the exception: `Array.Clear(scoreArray, 0, scoreArray.Length)`

Comment: I left them out, because I didnt think they were causing the error.